# SQL*Net Protocol specification for Oracle 12c

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle12c

In our project we have Oracle jdbc direct driver. This driver wrote some guys from our team but this  guys leave team. This driver working correct with Oracle 11g but throw and exception with Oracle 12c database trying to connect.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [mobius][Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol

at com.mobius.jdbc.oraclebase.BaseExceptions40.createAppropriateSQLExceptionInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mobius.jdbc.oraclebase.BaseExceptions40.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
at com.mobius.jdbc.oraclebase.BaseExceptions.createException(Unknown Source)
at com.mobius.jdbc.oraclebase.BaseExceptions.getException(Unknown Source)
at com.mobius.jdbc.oracle.OracleImplConnection.connectAndAuthenticate(Unknown Source)
at com.mobius.jdbc.oracle.OracleImplConnection.open(Unknown Source)
at com.mobius.jdbc.oraclebase.BaseConnection.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at com.mobius.jdbc.oraclebase.BaseConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at com.mobius.jdbc.oraclebase.BaseConnection.setupImplConnection(Unknown Source)
at com.mobius.jdbc.oraclebase.BaseConnection.open(Unknown Source)
at com.mobius.jdbc.oraclebase.BaseDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
... 52 more
```

It's possible to change in values **sqlnet.ora**

```
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER=8
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT=8
```

But this is not solution. Can you help to found out difference between communication protocol in Oracle 12c and 11g.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly which driver you're using (type and version, preferably exactly which jar); and what version of the database you're connecting to? I think you're saying the database changed from 11g to 12c and you're trying to keep using the same older JDBC driver, is that right? [The supported combinations are listed here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_02).

Comment: The problem that we using own jdbc driver which implement sql*net protocol specification. Oracle 11g used sql*net version=8 as default but Oracle 12c used version=10 as default. May be I wrong but I can't found out more information.

Comment: @Sergey Bartoshik are you sure? I think Oracle keeps it secret. And as far as I know there is no support for this protocol in any network traffic analyzer.

Comment: I think it's very very unlikely that your previous developer wrote their own driver, since the SQL*Net protocol isn't public. It's more likely to be wrapper around the driver. See if your project is linking any Oracle classes or packages (ojdbc6.jar, for example). Or if you have the source for the com.mobius.jdbc.oraclebase.BaseDriver class, see if it's importing any oracle.* classes?

Comment: Frankly speaking I don't have enough information about this driver. So you give me another peace of puzzle. Thanks! Going to look for full scenery. By the way interesting that I found out this article http://www.pythian.com/blog/repost-oracle-protocol/ So probably sql*net is not proprietary protocol but I can't found newest protocol version.

Comment: Someone reverse-engineering it doesn't mean it isn't proprietary; the fact it needed to be reverse-enginnered supports that it hasn't been published. I guess it would be possible write your own driver based on that, but what would be the point? It would be a lot of work to create an unsupported version of something you can get for free anyway, and which would break whenever the real protocol changed.

Comment: SQL-Net is a proprietary protocol.